# User role-hierarchy

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I make my bot not give a user a role or ban a member above them due to role hierarchy like this https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/223867697312694272/723382952330919976/image0.png

Instead my bot allows the user to add the role above them to themselves or other users as long as they have the required permissions https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/223867697312694272/723382993384767550/image0.png

My code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("You don't have permissions to use this!");

    let xdemb = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle("Role Command")
        .addField("Description:", `Adds/removes a role to/from a member`, true)
        .addField("Usage:", "\`?role\` [user] roleName", true)
        .addField("Example:" ,"\`?role\` @user goodrole", true)

    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if(!member) return message.channel.send(xdemb)

    let role = args.slice(2).join(" ")
    if(!role) return message.channel.send("Provide a role to assign")

    let gRole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name.toLowerCase() === role.toLowerCase())
    if(!gRole) return message.channel.send(`There's no role with the name \`${role}\``)


    if(member.roles.has(gRole.id)) {
        member.removeRole(gRole.id)
        message.channel.send(`Removed role \`${role}\` from **${member.user.username}**`)
    } else {
        member.addRole(gRole.id)
        message.channel.send(`Added role \`${role}\` to **${member.user.username}**`)
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "role"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Role` class in Discord.js has a [`position`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=position) property which represents its position in the role manager.

The `GuildMember` class has a property named [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles), which is of type `GuildMemberRoleManager`. The `GuildMemberRoleManager` class has a property named [`highest`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=highest), which points to the highest ranked role that the member has.

So. To make sure that the bot doesn't give a member a role that is higher than them in the hierarchy, you can compare the `position` of the role they want with the `position` of their current highest role.

Comment: right. I know, but, the thing is, I don’t know how to. Can you help me?

Comment: @Maniac  if `gRole.position > member.roles.highest.position`, then you know that the requested role is too high.

Answer (score 0):

The lowest role (@everyone) is at position 0.

To compare roles, try this:

```js
// define member as a GuildMember and role as a Role
if (member.roles.highest.position < role.position) return message.channel.send('You do not have permission to add this role as the role is above your highest role.');
```

Hope this helps.