# Discord.js kick / ban command top roles

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, members who have ban permissions cannot ban, which is good. But those who have ban permissions can ban those with higher roles than them, which means a mod can ban an admin if he has ban permissions. I want it so that you can't ban members with higher roles than you, even if you have ban permissions.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name : 'kick',
    description : 'Kick',
    async execute(message, args) {
        console.log("Works");
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You do not have permissions to use this command");
    
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if (!reason) reason = "No specified reason.";
    
        const kickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${member.user.tag} was kicked from ${message.guild.name}`)
        .setDescription(`Reason: ${reason}`)
        .setColor("#FF0000")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setAuthor(member.user.tag, member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic : true}))
        .setThumbnail(member.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
        
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`You need to specify the user that is going to be kicked`);
        if (!member) return message.channel.send(`The member you mentioned is not in the server`);
    
    try {
        await member.send(kickEmbed);
    } 
    catch(err){
        console.log(`I was unable to message the member`);
    }

    try {
        member.kick(reason);
        await message.channel.send(kickEmbed);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        message.channel.send("I was unable to kick the member you mentioned");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62463118/user-role-hierarchy has the same question about you about getting the levels of permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User role-hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62463118/user-role-hierarchy)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'highest' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<message>.member.roles.position.highest` to determine the position of a member role and apply an appropriate fix

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name : 'kick',
    description : 'Kick',
    async execute(message, args) {
        console.log("Works");
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You do not have permissions to use this command");
    
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if (!reason) reason = "No specified reason.";
    
        const kickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${member.user.tag} was kicked from ${message.guild.name}`)
        .setDescription(`Reason: ${reason}`)
        .setColor("#FF0000")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setAuthor(member.user.tag, member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic : true}))
        .setThumbnail(member.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
        
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`You need to specify the user that is going to be kicked`);
        if (!member) return message.channel.send(`The member you mentioned is not in the server`);
    
    // the fix for your issue

    if (member.roles.highest.position >= message.member.roles.highest.position) return message.reply('Yikes the person you tried to kick has higher or equal roles than you!')
    
    try {
        await member.send(kickEmbed);
    } 
    catch(err){
        console.log(`I was unable to message the member`);
    }

    try {
        member.kick(reason);
        await message.channel.send(kickEmbed);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        message.channel.send("I was unable to kick the member you mentioned");
    }
    }
}
```